# Checking value of 2 mapping with struct in the same address on blockchain

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

im new with blockchain and solidity and im trying to check 2 mapping result with the same key on one address, suppose i have this code

```
contract EventConfirmAccess{

struct eventStruct{
    string event_log_time;
    string event_name;
    string event_id;
    uint data_nik;
}
mapping(uint => eventStruct) public dictConfirmAccess;
uint[] public arrayOfData;

function loggingAccess(
    uint _nik, string memory _event_log_time,
    string memory _event_name, string memory _event_id,
    uint _data_nik
) public{
    dictConfirmAccess[_nik] = eventStruct(
      {
        event_log_time : _event_log_time,
        event_name : _event_name,
        event_id : _event_id,
        data_nik : _data_nik
      }
    );

    arrayOfData.push(_nik);
}
function checkData(uint _nik) view public returns(
        string memory ,string memory,
        string memory ,uint
    ){
        return (
            dictConfirmAccess[_nik].event_log_time,
            dictConfirmAccess[_nik].event_name,
            dictConfirmAccess[_nik].event_id,
            dictConfirmAccess[_nik].data_nik
        );
    }
 }
```

supposed I insert 1st data to blockchain :

- loggingAccess(10001, "2020-10-11 08:10:00", "CONFIRM_1", "C_1", 10001)

after that I insert 2nd data :

- loggingAccess(10001, "2020-10-11 08:20:00", "CONFIRM_2", "C_2", 10002)

when I check the array with checkData function I get result like this :

```
    Result {
  '0': '2020-10-11 08:20:00',
  '1': 'CONFIRM_2',
  '2': 'C_2',
  '3': BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [ 51784655, 4, <1 empty item> ],
    length: 2,
    red: null
  }
}
```

the question is where is the result of 1st array ? how to retrieve it from blockchain? is this removed from blockchain (as far as i know  blockchain data recorded forever ) ?

thankyou for you help and answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're storing to the mapping under the same key (`dictConfirmAccess[_nik] = ...`), the value gets **overwritten**.

Using the Remix VM emulator, it's currently not possible to access the previous states.

If this situation happened on a live network, you could connect to an [archive node](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#archive-node) and retrieve the historical value using the combination of

1. the storage slot number

   *determinable, based on the property order in the contract and the mapping key - [source](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage)*
2. and the block number

   *for which you want to get the value*

For example using the web3 [getStorageAt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html#getstorageat) method

```
const historicalValue = await web3.eth.getStorageAt(
    contractAddress,
    storageSlotNumber,
    blockNumber
);
```

Note that the historical values are accessible only using off-chain tools and are not accessible from the contract itself (or other contracts).

Comment: thank you @Petr for the answer. so you say that blockchain will overwrite the existing data with new data. is this not breaking the rule that data in blockchain cant be removed/erased?

Comment: The data is not removed from the blockchain - you can still access it using an archive node. It's only made unavailable for the contracts, because they can only access the current (and not historic) state.

Comment: okay i got the point. thankyou @Petr